# Iterate over properties from a PropertySource Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I'm trying to expose all properties from some propertysources through an endpoint in my application. I can use MutablePropertySources to get all the propertySources available in the Environment, but my question is how to iterate over a propertySource?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution, you basically need to use EnumrablePropertySource instead of a propertySource and use that to get an Array of names(keys) then use that to get the value by calling env.getProperty(name)

The code would be somethin like this:
EnumerablePropertySource propertySource=(EnumerablePropertySource) configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources().get(SOME_PROPERTYSOURCE_NAME);
Arrays.stream(propertySource.getPropertyNames()).forEach(s->System.out.println(s+"="+configurableEnvironment.getProperty(s)));